# How to manages/ store images on web server appengine via android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am working on android application that requires to register the user with some details and image associted with each user. I am using Google Appengine with Google Cloud SQL to make it possible. I am stuck when i required to upload image associated with users detail.

I am not able to figure out how should i manage images on server. In my search i have come to know that its better to create filesystem for storing images and associate that path to corresponding details of users within Cloud SQL.

Is it possible with, appengine and Google cloud SQL bcz i have read that we can't manage filesysten on appengine server as it doesn't facilitates [write permission](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#writefile) , If yes, please guide me how can i get forward to this by any resources or tutorial.

Or any alternative solution  ??????

Comment: Well you can do one thing that while uploading file to Google Cloud Storage or Blobstore, you will get a blobkey in response which you can save in your DB table by creating an extra field, and when you need to serve that file, just pass the blobkey to get the file served.